# JAVA_HOME error on “ionic build android”

Tags: build, ionic-framework, java-home

I am trying to build an Ionic application with `ionic build android` with no success. I looked around answers in stackoverflow but I can seem to have the same situation.

I get the following error:

```
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/myuserID/development/android-sdk-macosx  
 JAVA_HOME=/Users/myuserID/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_71.jdk/Co>nten
ts/home
Running:     
>/Users/myuserID/development/ionic/keepdoing/platforms/android/gradlew 
cdvBuildDebug -b 
/Users/myuserID/development/ionic/keepdoing/platforms/android/build.gradle - 
Dorg.gradle.daemon=true

ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory:     
/Users/myuserID/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_71.jdk/Contents/hom>e

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.
```

I have everything set in the **.bash_profile**:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/myuserID/development/android-sdk-macosx/platform-    
tools
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/myuserID/development/android-sdk-macosx/tools
export ANDROID_HOME="/Users/myuserID/development/android-sdk-macosx"
export    
JAVA_HOME="/Users/myuserID/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_71.jdk
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/share/npm/bin
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/npm/bin
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/
export      
PATH=$PATH:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_71.jdk/Contents/home/bin
export PATH=$PATH:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_71.jdk
```

But can't resolve this. Re-installed the android SDK to no avail.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: could you please run $env and check JAVA_HOME env variable. It seems 
your .bash_profile has some error.

try setting manual

You can also check using $echo $JAVA_HOME

Comment: I did and got this: myComputer$ env $JAVA_HOME
env: /Users/MyUserID/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_71.jdk: No such file or directory

Answer (score 13):

A recent update to Android Studio should help anyone landing on this question in 2017! Android Studio 2.2+ comes bundled with a custom OpenJDK build, so there's no need to download a separate JDK.

The following are the adjusted instructions available at https://ionicframework.com/docs/developer-resources/platform-setup/mac-setup.html using the new locations bundled with Android Studio app.

Create and open the .bash_profile file in your favourite text editor:

```
touch ~/.bash_profile
open -a TextEdit ~/.bash_profile`
```

Populate the file with:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home

export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:$PATH

# Set Android_HOME
export ANDROID_HOME=~/Library/Android/sdk/

# Add the Android SDK to the ANDROID_HOME variable
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH

#Set GRADLE_HOME
export GRADLE_HOME=/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-3.2
export PATH=$PATH:$GRADLE_HOME/bin
```

Save and close the file, then apply these changes by re-sourcing .bash_profile:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

You'll then be able to run the ionic commands using the built in tools within Android Studio.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful! Also worth pointing out that the version of gradle might be different (at time of writing it's 4.4) - so the path to GRADLE_HOME may be different.

Answer (score 0):

You have an unnecessary double quotes before the java home path in .pash_profile. Remove it.

```
JAVA_HOME="/Users/myuserID/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_71.jdk
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It did not help, though.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all who answered.

Eventually I stumbled on an answer here: 
http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-set-java_home-environment-variable-on-mac-os-x/

in essence In Mac OSX 10.5 or later, Apple recommends to set the $JAVA_HOME variable to /usr/libexec/java_home, just export $JAVA_HOME in file ~/. bash_profile or ~/.profile.

Pagugim